# look if created_at have passed 24 hours in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I am trying to check if the last message in a conversation has passes 24hrs but I keep getting false

```
message_tag= conversation.messages.incoming.last.created_at > 24.hours.ago
```

even though I have changed the created time to be 25.hours.ago `message.created_at=25.hours.ago`

what could be causing this??

Comment: Try using reload to check you're not getting a cached response - `conversation.reload.messages.incoming.last.created_at > 24.hours.ago`

Comment: @Jon it is still False

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the correct message?

Comment: @Jon yeah I am sure

Comment: Then the date must be wrong? I'd probably start by writing a unit test to cover the expected behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are expecting `message_tag` to be `true` when message is older than 24hrs from now & `false` otherwise, you have to modify the condition i.e. `<` instead of `>`.

```
message_tag = conversation.messages.incoming.last.created_at < 24.hours.ago
```

For ex :-

```
[3] pry(main)> Time.now < 24.hours.ago
=> false
[4] pry(main)> 25.hours.ago  < 24.hours.ago
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it as conversation.messages.incoming.last.created_at < 24.hours.ago

Comment: do you have any idea why that happens?? it is so confusing

Comment: You can check if the both the time format are same. You can change both the time to UTC.